# Python: Is pandas the right thing to use?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to take a 1.8mB txt file.  There are couple of header lines afterwards its all space separated data.  I can pull the data off using pandas.  What I'm wanting to do with the data is:

1) Cut out the non essential data. ie the first 1675 lines, roughly I want to remove and the last 3-10 lines, varies day to day, I also want to remove.  I can remove the first lines, kind of.  The big problem with this idea I'm having right now is knowing for sure where the 1675 pointer location is.  Using something like

```
    df = df[df.year > 1978]
```

only moves the initial 'pointer' to 1675.  If I try

```
   dataf = df[df.year > 1978]
```

it just gives me a pure copy of what I would have with the first line.  It still keeps the pointer to the same 1675 start point.  It won't allow me to access any of the first 1675 rows but they are still obviously there.

```
    df.year[0]
```

It comes back with an error suggesting row 0 doesn't exist.  I have to go out and search to find what the first readable row is...instead of flat out removing the rows and moving the new pointer up to 0 it just moves the pointer to 1675 and won't allow access to anything lower than that.  I still haven't found a way to be able to determine what the last row number is through programming, through the shell it's easy but I need to be able to do it through the program so I can set up the loop for point 2.

2) I want to be able to take averages of the data, 'x' day moving averages and create a new column with the new data once I have calculated the moving average.  I think I can create the new column with the Series statement...I think...I haven't tried it yet though as I haven't been able to get this far yet.

3) After all this and some more math I want to be able to graph the data with a homemade graph.  I think this should be easy once I have everything else completed.  I have already created the sample graph and can plot the points/lines on the graph once I have the data to work with.

Is panda the right lib for the project or should I be trying to use something else?  So far the more research I do...the more lost I get as everything I keep trying gets me a little further but sets me even further back at the same time.  In something similar I saw mention using something else when wanting to do math on the data block.  Their wasn't any indication as to what he used though.

Comment: It sounds like pandas will really help, but at the moment we can't help as there are too many parts to this question and no example...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you main trouble is indexing. If you want to refer to the "first" thing in a DataFrame, use `df.iloc[0]`. But DataFrame indexes are really powerful regardless.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: If I go df.iloc[0] all I end up with 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'iloc'.  If I go df it comes up with the key line Int64Index: 12766 entries, 1675 to 14440.  Obviously there is something there.  How do I find out that 1675 is the first row with 'usable' data and 14440 is the last row?  I want to be able to do this through the program not through the shell.  What I'm wanting to write up is a stand alone program not a shell routine.

Comment: If `iloc` isn't there you may be on an older version of pandas.

Comment: @confused upgrade pandas 0.12 is stable, 0.13rc also available.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are headed in the right direction. Pandas gives you nice, high level control over your data so that you can manipulate it much more easily than using traditional logic. It will take some work to learn. Work through their tutorials and you should be fine. But don't gloss over them or you'll miss some important details.

I'm not sure why you are concerned that the lines you want to ignore aren't being deleted as long as they aren't used in your analysis, it doesn't really matter. Unless you are facing memory constraints, it's probably irrelevant. But, if you do find you can't afford to keep them around, I'm sure there is a way to really remove them, even if it's a bit sideways.

Processing a few megabytes worth of data is pretty easy these days and Pandas will handle it without any problems. I believe you can easily pass pandas data to numpy for your statistical calculations. You should double check that, though, before taking my word for it. Also, they mention matplotlib on the pandas website, so I am guessing it will be easy to do basic graphing as well.

Comment: How do you go about telling what the start point is once you 'crop' the lines/rows.  I know I've already tried the idea of for a in range(0, df) only to get the error that it isn't an integer.  How do I access the range of the data.  I would need to know both the new start row and the last row.